# Hot air balloon tearing

Tags: material-science, bubbles

What will happen if there is a tearing in hot air balloon?
Is there a difference between pressure so the balloon will be pushed?
I have tried ti read a lot of essays but there was no answer!

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Can you be more specific about what you want to know? "What will happen" is rather generic - what aspect of the situation are you interested in specifically?

Answer (score 2):

there are two answers to this.

If the tear is small, (because modern hot air balloons are made of "rip stop" material, a small tear should not spread) then it may not be noticed by the pilot, except that more gas will be used to maintain height.

The question I think you are after is based on an incorrect assumption that the pressure in the balloon is very high, so that escaping hot air will act like a mini rocket engine.  The pressure is never that high so the balloon will still follow the direction of the prevailing wind, as it did before the tear occurred.

A large tear is probably due to some far more serious cause, such as hitting a power line.

Comment: Good answer. Is there any pressure difference at all in a hot air balloon? As the balloon is already open to the outside air at the burner hole.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your comment, have a look at this page:

[Hot Air Ballons](https://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/flight/modern/hot-air-balloon6.htm).

You would work the pressure difference easily enough. Find out how long a canister of fuel lasts. I have been close up to a balloon, I think 4 canisters gives you a flight time of a few hours.

The balloons walls do look rigid, but they are not, as a few tragic accident videos will show you, as the balloons flew over windy areas, they "candled", that is  they collapsed inwards very quickly.